# SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Upgrade Blog Category Link Issues

Tags: 2013, upgrade, blog, categories

**The Problem:**

We upgraded from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 and it went very well overall. One issue that I've found is that if I open the blog subsite and select a category, it correctly returns all the blog posts for that category but all the links on the results page including the titles of the blogs point to a generic `.../blog/Lists/Categories/` link. This includes the category web part that shows a list of all the categories on the left. The links on the home page of the blog (`default.aspx`) are correct being:

(Category List Web Part): `/blog/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId=15&Name={Name}`

(Blog title link): `/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=87`

But if I select a category from the web part on `default.aspx`, it shows all those posts correctly but on the `Category.aspx` page the links show as:

(Category List Web Part): `/blog/Lists/Categories/`

(Blog title link): `/blog/Lists/Categories/`

The same thing seems to happen when I open a blog post from the `default.aspx` page except that the links on `post.aspx` show as:

(Category List Web Part): `/blog/Lists/Posts/`

(Blog title link): `/blog/Lists/Posts/`

I found this link http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/sharepoint-blog-posts-not-filtered-9668.aspx although it specifically deals with the filters not being applied which isn't the case here but I'm suspecting that something on the web parts of `category.aspx` and `post.aspx` is losing/not being passed settings correctly.

**The Question:**

Does anyone know why this would happen or what could be causing it and if anyone has encountered the same thing, what steps were taken to fix it?

**Resolution:**

I have resolved this issue by adding the "Blog Tools" on both the category.aspx and post.aspx pages. I'm guessing something is different in SP2013 that renders the links for the other web parts on the page (the Categories web part in the BlogNavigator zone and the Posts web part in the main zone) that wasn't there in SP2010 as category.aspx and post.aspx didn't have the Blog Tools (previously Admin Links) on them.

When looking at the code for the page it was this line of code that made me try adding the Blog Tools web part to the page:

```
<WebPartPages:BlogAdminWebPart runat="server" PostUrl="Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID={ID}" CategoryUrl="Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId={CategoryId}"
```

as that was missing from the 2010 pages but was the links that were "broken"

Comment: I can reproduce the issue if removing the BlogTools Webpart from my default.aspx page.
Thanks for the advise :)
ps. my case applies to Sharepoint Online.

Comment: Yes you need to Add Blog Tools webpart to the webpage it works. Thanks it saves me .